# Elements of one section's container invading and overlapping another section

Tags: html, css, flexbox, safari, css-grid

I created a website ([www.btcatm.ru](http://www.btcatm.ru)) and in one section of it (desktop version) the box elements of my container invade the next section overlapping it, but this seems to happen only on Safari, as you can see from the first photo:

[image: safari]

On chrome instead, the design appear correct as it is visible on second photo:

[image: chrome]

How do I solve this problem? Seems no one is able to help me.

```css
* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

*::before,
*::after {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

html {
  font-size: 62.5%;
}

body {
  font-family: "Rubik", sans-serif;
  color: #444;
  padding: 0 /* 1rem */;
}


.why-us {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  background-color: #efeeee;
}

.why-us-title h2 {
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 3rem;
  margin-top: 3.2rem;
}

.why-us-title h3 {
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 2.4rem;
  font-style: italic;
  color: #f2a900;
  opacity: 85%;
  margin-top: 0.6rem;
}

.why-us-boxes {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr;
  column-gap: 6rem;
  margin: 6rem 8rem 12.8rem 8rem;
}

.why-us-boxes h2 {
  text-transform: uppercase;
  /* color: #f2a900; */
  font-style: italic;
}

.prova2 h2 {
  display: inline-block;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  color: #f2a900;
  font-style: italic;
  line-height: 3rem;
  letter-spacing: 3px;
}

.contacts {
  width: 100%;
}

.contacts-container {
  display: flex;
  margin: 11rem auto;
  position: relative;
  width: 50%;
}

.contacts-container img {
  height: 40rem;
  width: auto;
  background-size: cover;
}

.contacts-txt {
  position: absolute;
  top: 1.2rem;
  left: 13rem;
  /* color: #fff6e4; */
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 3rem;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-family: inherit;
}

.contacts-txt2 {
  color: #fceecc;
}

/* ----- form ----- */

.contacts-form {
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #fceecc;
  bottom: -9.8rem;
  left: 20rem;
  box-shadow: 4px 6px 5px rgba(115, 115, 115, 0.102);
  padding: 1.8rem;
  font-size: 1.8rem;
  color: #333;
}

.contacts-form h2 {
  text-transform: uppercase;
  margin-bottom: 1.8rem;
}

.form-title {
  color: #f7cb66; 
}

.form-title2 {
  color: #f2a900;
}

input[type="text"],
select,
textarea {
  width: 100%;
  padding: 12px;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  border-radius: 4px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin-top: 6px;
  margin-bottom: 16px;
  resize: vertical;
}

input[type="email"],
select,
textarea {
  width: 100%;
  padding: 12px;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  border-radius: 4px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin-top: 6px;
  margin-bottom: 16px;
  resize: vertical;
}

input[type="submit"] {
  background-color: #f2a900;
  color: white;
  padding: /*  12px 20px; */ 1.3rem;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 1.8rem;
  cursor: pointer;
  font-size: 1.8rem;
}

input[type="submit"]:hover {
  color: #fceecc;
  padding: 1.2rem;
}

input:focus,
textarea:focus {
  outline: none !important;
  border-color: #f2a900;
  box-shadow: 0 0 8px #f2a900;
}

.contacts-btn {
  height: 50px;
}
```

```html
<section class="why-us" id="why-box">
  <div class="why-us-title">
    <h2>Why us</h2>
    <h3>..you won't regret chosing us</h3>
  </div>
<div class="why-us-boxes">
  <div class="container3">  <h2 class="why-title">fixed<br />
    commission</h2><br>
    <span class="why-txt"> At all our ATMs you will find a fixed commission of just <strong>8%</strong> from official quotation</span></div>
  <div class="container3"><h2 class="why-title">24/7<br />
    support</h2><br>
    <span class="why-txt">We have a customer service active 24/7 through the hotline or through this site</span></div>
  <div class="container3"><h2 class="why-title">4 years<br />
    expertise</h2><br>
  <span class="why-txt">Our team is formed by cryptocurrencies experts and is ready to help you anytime</span></div>

</div>
</section>

<section class="contacts">
  
 <div class="contacts-container">
  <img class="contacts-pic" src="images/atm2.png" />
  <div class="contacts-txt">
    contact <span class="contacts-txt2">us</span>
  </div>

  <div class="contacts-form">
    <form action="process-form.php" method="post">
      <h2 class="form-title">Get in <span class="form-title2">touch</span></h2>
      <label for="fname">First Name:</label>
      <input type="text" id="fname" name="firstname" placeholder="Your name..">
      <label for="email">Enter your email:</label>
      <input type="email" id="email" name="email" placeholder="Write your email..">
      <label for="subject">Subject:</label>
      <textarea id="subject" name="subject" placeholder="Write something.." style="height:100px"></textarea>
      <div class="contacts-btn">
        <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit">
      </div>
    </form>
  </div>
</div>

</section>
```

I have also posted the code snipped of these 2 sections. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
.container3 {
  height: min-content;
  padding: 10px;
}
```